# GMF: Acces active gmf node through selection service

Tags: service, selection, xtext, eclipse-gmf

I'm using Xtext and GMF and therefor I would like to acces the active GMF compartment node from my xtext project. Because of this, I thought that the selection service of eclipse would be a good way to solve this.

I tried to implement the selection service, but it didn't seems to acces the GMF related node. Rather that I get an xtext class object, because I implemented an IXtextAwareEditPart in GMF. Is there a way to acces the active GMF node?
This code hasn't work for me so far:

```
   ISelectionService selectionService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getSelectionService();
   ISelection selection = selectionService.getSelection();
   if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
     IStructuredSelection iStructuredSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
     if (iStructuredSelection.getFirstElement() instanceof PartImpl) {
        PartImpl partImpl = (PartImpl) iStructuredSelection;  // <------ The xtext class?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of PartImpl, the object returned from iStructuredSelection.getFirstElement() will be a GMF Edit Part (e.g. PartEditPart).  Try something like the following:

```
PartEditPart editPart = (PartEditPart) iStructuredSelection.getFirstElement();
ShapeImpl shapeImpl = (ShapeImpl) editPart.getModel();
PartImpl partImpl = (PartImpl) shapeImpl.getElement();
```